# MS SQL 2008 join - select one from many results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I'm trying to run the following query, but am not sure how to limit it to one result only.
In the query below, the client that clientcontactid 21901 works for has 2 address meaning that 2 results return.

Query:

```
select  cc.contactpersonid,
    cc.clientcontactid,
    ad.city,
    ad.addressid
from SavedList sl
inner join ClientContacts cc on cc.ContactPersonId = sl.ObjectId
inner join Clients c on c.ClientID = cc.ClientId
inner join Address ad on c.ClientID = ad.ObjectId
where sl.SavedListId = 2117
```

Results:

```
contactpersonid clientcontactid city    addressid
87934           21901                   145186
87934           21901           London  1130705
89778           17275           Leeds   145368
```

I need to return one of those results for client contact **21901**, with the priority being on the one with the city in it.  I've tried select **top (1)** but I think it's down to the join forcing multiple record back.  Any help on how to return only 1 result, and how to control that would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
;WITH a AS (
select  cc.contactpersonid,
    cc.clientcontactid,
    ad.city,
    ad.addressid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cc.clientcontactid ORDER BY ad.city DESC) AS RowNum
    from SavedList sl
    inner join ClientContacts cc on cc.ContactPersonId = sl.ObjectId
    inner join Clients c on c.ClientID = cc.ClientId
    inner join Address ad on c.ClientID = ad.ObjectId
    where sl.SavedListId = 2117
)

SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

What I normally do to prioritize results, is to actually assign a priority value column. In this case it can be kept simple because there is only one priority: records with cities come before cities without:

```
with q as(
select  cc.contactpersonid,
    cc.clientcontactid,
    ad.city,
    ad.addressid,
    case when ad.city is null then 0 else 1 end prior
from SavedList sl
inner join ClientContacts cc on cc.ContactPersonId = sl.ObjectId
inner join Clients c on c.ClientID = cc.ClientId
inner join Address ad on c.ClientID = ad.ObjectId
where sl.SavedListId = 2117
)
select top 1 * from q order by prior desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Big but it works:

```
select  cc.contactpersonid,
        cc.clientcontactid,
        ad.city,
        ad.addressid
from SavedList sl
inner join ClientContacts cc on cc.ContactPersonId = sl.ObjectId
inner join Clients c on c.ClientID = cc.ClientId
inner join Address ad on c.ClientID = ad.ObjectId
where sl.SavedListId = 2117 and (ad.city is not null or ad.city <> '')
UNION
select  cc.contactpersonid,
        cc.clientcontactid,
        ad.city,
        ad.addressid
from SavedList sl
inner join ClientContacts cc on cc.ContactPersonId = sl.ObjectId
inner join Clients c on c.ClientID = cc.ClientId
inner join Address ad on c.ClientID = ad.ObjectId
where sl.SavedListId = 2117 and (ad.city is null or ad.city = '')
and cc.clientcontactid not in (
  select  cc.clientcontactid
  from SavedList sl
  inner join ClientContacts cc on cc.ContactPersonId = sl.ObjectId
  inner join Clients c on c.ClientID = cc.ClientId
  inner join Address ad on c.ClientID = ad.ObjectId
  where sl.SavedListId = 2117 and (ad.city is not null or ad.city <> '')
)
```

Comment: You're right - it's big but it does work!  Just out of interest, is there any difference between **ad.city is not null or ad.city <> ''** and **isnull(ad.city,'')<>''** ?

Comment: @sam.clements nop, you can use `isnull` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `select top 1 record` by adding the condition where `city is not NULL`.

Comment: The problem with putting where city is not null is there are some records that will have a null in city and I'm happy to return those if there is no alternative.
Where would you put the select top 1? If it goes in the top, then it will only return the top line with clientcontact 21901 and won't return the one for clientcontact 17275!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT cc.contactpersonid,
                cc.clientcontactid,
                ad.city,
                ad.addressid,
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cc.clientcontactid ORDER BY CASE WHEN ad.city <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) rn
         FROM   SavedList sl
                INNER JOIN ClientContacts cc
                  ON cc.ContactPersonId = sl.ObjectId
                INNER JOIN Clients c
                  ON c.ClientID = cc.ClientId
                INNER JOIN Address ad
                  ON c.ClientID = ad.ObjectId
         WHERE  sl.SavedListId = 2117)
SELECT contactpersonid,
       clientcontactid,
       city,
       addressid
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```