# Exposing more fields on group by sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

*I know, in a `Group By` you can't `Select` a field that is not in an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.*

However, There must be a workaround using joins or something else.

I have TWO tables BMP_VISITS_SITES and BMP_VISITS_COMMENTS which are connected by StationID in a one-to-many relationship. One Site can have many comments.

I'm trying to write a query that returns all Sites and the latest (only 1) comment. I have a "working" query but it only returns two columns which are in either an aggregate function or group by.

**Here is my "working" query:**

```
select          a.StationID, 
                MAX(b.[dateobserved]) as LastDateObserved,
                a.Status
from            BMP_VISITS_SITES a
left outer join BMP_VISITS_COMMENTS as b 
on a.[StationID] = b.[StationID]
group by a.StationID;
```

**But how can I access all the columns in both tables?**

I've tried inner joins with 1/2 success. When I join my BMP_VISITS_SITES to the above query I get all the fields of the table (t1). Great, but as soon as I try joining on BMP_VISITS_COMMENTS (t3) I get more results than I should.

```
select          t1.*, t2.*
                --,t3.* 
                from BMP_VISITS_SITES t1
inner join (
        select a.StationID, MAX(b.[dateobserved]) as LastDateObserved from BMP_VISITS_SITES a
        left outer join BMP_VISITS_COMMENTS as b 
        on a.[StationID] = b.[StationID]
        group by a.StationID
) t2 on t2.StationID = t1.StationID
--inner join sde.BMP_VISITS_COMMENTS t3 on t3.StationID = t2.StationID;
```

Comment: Have a look at a question that I posed - may help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116438/ms-sql-2008-join-select-one-from-many-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM
BMP_VISITS_SITES a
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM BMP_VISITS_COMMENTS b
    WHERE b.StationID = a.StationID
    ORDER BY LastDateObserved DESC
) b
```

You can use apply to get the last comment record and return all fields from both sides of the query.

Comment: Wow, clean, short, effective and simply genius. And I got to learn a new trick "outer apply" Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select * 
from 
(
    select          a.StationID, 
                    a.Status,
                    b.*,
                    row_number() over (partition by a.stationid, a.status order by b.[dateobserved] desc) as rn
    from            BMP_VISITS_SITES a
    left outer join BMP_VISITS_COMMENTS as b 
    on a.[StationID] = b.[StationID]
) v
where rn = 1
```